# What conditions set an upper bound to the number of roots of a real function?

Tags: calculus, functions, roots

Let $f$ be a real function. Which conditions on $f$ let me give an upper bound to the number of roots of $f$?
I'm intentionally vague on the conditions of $f$, everything it's ok.
I would like to have some non-trivial general result, I think this statement should be true:

If $f \in C^k(I)$ and $f^{(k)}$ has exactly $m$ roots then $f$ has at most $m+k$ roots.

Anything better?

Comment: Have you heard of [Rollé's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem)?

Comment: @rtybase: that is not inconsistent with the "at most" in the question

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667634/relationship-between-f-and-f-in-terms-of-number-of-real-non-real-roots

Answer (score 2):

By the MVT, for any two roots $x,y$ of $f$, there is a root of $f'$ in $(x,y)$. Thus, if $f$ has $n$ roots, $f'$ has at least $n-1$ roots. Inductively, this means $f^{(k)}$ has at least $n-k$ roots. Hence $n>m+k$, would contradict the fact that $f^{(k)}$ has exactly $m$ roots.